# Add two columns in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm running into a bit of a problem which I'm guessing there exists an easy solution to which I've overlooked.

I'm trying to add a column to a pivot table that is the sum of two other columns **in the pivot table**. All of the documentation that I've seen has told me how to make a calculated field based on the columns in the original data set.

I've added a column to the right of my pivot table that does exactly what I want - summing columns B and C in the pivot table:

[image: Nooooo Pivot Tables]

Unfortunately this column is not considered as part of the pivot table so pivot charts do not include it.

There HAS to be an easy solution to this that I'm overlooking. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards,

MoarCodePlz

Comment: You mentioned calculated fields, which is a good way to go, but don't say whether you tried it.

Comment: @DougGlancy - Calculated fields, from what I can tell, can only calculate based on data from the original data sheet. In this case, I need to calculate a third column in the pivot table based on two other columns in the pivot table, which I do not believe I can do with calculated fields.

Comment: Your other option is to sum them in the source and include that source field in the pivot.

Comment: @DougGlancy - Please tell more if I can do that with Pivot Table columns! The problem is that I want to add the average and standard deviation of a column from my data set as a third column to my pivot table. As such I cannot sum them in the source (the source has to be a flat sheet)!

Comment: Sorry, I've been show on the uptake. The problem with a calculated field here it's that it calculates at the row level, and then add those up, giving a huge numbe. Your current approach, combined with a regular chart, might be the best. The only other option I know it's to create a prorated colon in the source data, but that's ugly.

Comment: Actually, a column is preferable to a colon. :-)